# AttributeError at /employee/ 'function' object has no attribute 'delete'

Tags: python, django

I'm new in python and django, wanted to add a function to delete an employee, along with urls and html, the delete button came out just fine, but it didn't do anything, is there anything I did wrong, I've been researching but couldn't find the solution, please advice, thank you, here's the code:

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, Http404
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.forms import modelformset_factory

from .models import Employee
from .forms import EmployeeForm

def index(request):
    '''The home page for employee_record.'''
    return render(request, 'employee_records/base.html')    

@login_required
def employees(request):
    '''Shows all employees'''

    employees = Employee.objects.filter(owner=request.user).order_by('full_name')
    context = {'employees': employees}
    return render(request, 'employee_records/employees.html', context)

@login_required
def employee(request, employee_id):
    '''Show a single employee'''
    employee = Employee.objects.get(id=employee_id)
    # Make sure the employee belongs to the current user.
    if employee.owner != request.user:
        raise Http404

    EmployeeFormSet = modelformset_factory(Employee, fields=('full_name', 
        'address', 'city', 'state', 'zip', 'email', 'hire_date'), extra=0)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EmployeeFormSet(request.POST)
        employees = form.save(commit=False)
        for employee in employees:
            employee.save() 
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('employee_records:employees'))

    form = EmployeeFormSet(queryset=Employee.objects.filter(id=employee_id))

    context = {'employee': employee, 'form' : form}
    return render(request, 'employee_records/employee.html', context)

@login_required
def delete_employee(request):
    employee
    employee.delete()
    return redirect('employees')
```

urls.py

```
'''Defines URL patterns for employee_records.'''

from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'employee_records'
urlpatterns = [
# Home page
path('', views.employees, name='employees'),

# Detail page for a single employee
path('employees/<int:employee_id>/', views.employee, name='employee'),

# Detail page for delete a single employee
path('employee/', views.delete_employee, name='delete_employee'),

# Page for adding a new employee
path('new_employee/', views.new_employee, name='new_employee'),
]
```

employee.html

```
{% extends 'employee_records/employees.html' %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}

{% block content %}

{% if employee  %}

<form method='POST'>
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p}} 

  {% buttons %}
      <button input type='submit' class="btn btn-primary">submit</button>
    {% endbuttons %}    

</form> 

<a href="{% url 'employee_records:delete_employee' %}">

{% buttons %}
    <button input type='delete' class="btn btn-danger">delete</button>
  {% endbuttons %}    
</a>
{% endif %}

{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: (1) You have a `/delete` view but there is no way to pass an employee id. How is that view supposed to know which employee to delete, and (2) You have a method named `employee` and `employee.delete()` tries to run on that method.

Comment: you're right, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are confused about the **[`scope`](https://pythonspot.com/scope/)** of **`employee`**.  In your delete view, employee does **not** reference a queryset, or a model.  Instead, it references the ***employee view***, which is a function, hence your error.  To fix this you will need to execute the query directly in your `delete_employee` view, which means you will have to pass an id to your view (like you did in the employee view):

```
@login_required
def delete_employee(request, employee_id):
    employee = Employee.objects.get(id=employee_id)
    employee.delete()
    return redirect('employees')
```

Don't forget to change your `path` for this view so the `employee_id` gets passed to your view:

```
path('delete_employee/<int:employee_id>', views.delete_employee, name='delete_employee'),
```

The concept of scope is very important, so I would recommend doing some research on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in your this code block:

```
@login_required
def delete_employee(request):
    employee
    employee.delete()
    return redirect('employees')
```

Where `employee` is not an object.

You first have to get the Object of that specific `employee` then you will be able to delete.

Like:

```
employee_id = request.POST.get('employee_id')
# or
employee_id = request.GET.get('employee_id')
# whatever the way of sending employee_id
```

then:

```
employee = Employee.objects.get(id=employee_id)
employee.delete()
```

Then it will work.